# How to use Google Drive API to upload a video

Tags: android

I'm still new to Android but I want to ask how to properly use the GoogleDrive API. I want my app to upload a video to Google Drive after recording it. I found some tutorials but all of them use something called GoogleAccountsCredentials, and I don't know why but in my Android Studio I'm just able to use GoogleCredentials, but I found nothing on how to use it.

I'm super lost on this, so if someone could help me it would be really nice.

Thanks y'all

Comment: Did you find a solution?